AWR report open_cursor, session , processes parameter high number
I have AWR report from 2 databases and I am comparing parameters to understand if there are underlying problems
Rep1:

Rep2:

For open cursors usually I see in reports 500, here its showing 1200 and (3200+1600). How to assume its high number? Is there some tables or ways I can understand what the reason of such 'high numbers' ?
for process usually I see 1000 of value here , I am seeing 20000 and 1500, what does it mean ? and how high number affect the database (sga? i/o?)
I see high number of sessions , is it might of high parallel session but is it consider high ? how to know what are the cause of such sessions ?

These are initialization parameters.  Someone at some time decided to set open_cursors to a non-default value.  processes and sessions would generally be set at installation time based on the available hardware.  If these are set to non-default values, you'd need to ask whoever set them to those values why they did so.

open_cursors sets aside private process memory for every session and limits the number of cursors a session can have open at any one time. Normally this number is in the hundreds at most (default is 50). If you see something in the thousands, chances are you have had a poorly written app  that didn't properly close its cursors hitting the database at one point that forced a DBA to try to accommodate it by raising this parameter rather than telling the developers to fix the underlying issue. The amount of memory assigned however is quite small, so it should be thought of as more of a sanity check (if you have thousands of open cursors, you're doing something wrong and the app should fail so they can fix their design) than a resource concern, and certainly it has no performance implication. If a session reaches its limit, it will get an error, not slower performance.
sessions simply assigns the size of the array of struct that underlies x$ksuse which in turn underlies v$session. Because every SID requires an array position, this limits the total number of SIDs available, thus defining how many concurrent sessions can be in the instance. It's auto-calculated as a derivative of processes which is what you actually set. The larger this value, the more SGA memory will be consumed to hold these structures. In the big scheme of things, however, this is really quite minimal. However, exceedingly high values (and 30,000 is an extreme value) will cause performance problems for monitoring apps that scan v$session on a high-frequency basis, as the time to perform that scan is linear to the # of array elements, or the sessions parameter. Therefore this number should be well above what you actually need (2x-5x maybe) but not an order of magnitude more. A few thousand is typical - I rarely see anything about 10,000. Aside from the monitoring impact, however, this would not normally have any other performance implication. Again, these settings should employ reason and not just throw high numbers at them.
For further information, see Oracle docs on instance parameters, or talk to your DBA. These parameters are not normally something developers should have to be concerned with. There are hundreds of them and only some of them are directly related to performance, and none of them are as simple as "the larger the better". If you are having performance issues, your should focus first and foremost on your SQL and what it's doing wrong in its plan. It's only a very small percentage of cases where a perf problem is due to a database setting.
